# removeNode on last child node does not remove the arrow from the parent in Jquery tree table

Tags: php, jquery, treetable

Here, I show you,

[image]

**Issue :** where 250 HR Services,500 HR Services, 700 HR Services, 1000 HR Services is the last remaining child of a parent, that parent will still show the **plus sign** after the node is removed. The arrow should disappear since there are no more children.

implement using this reference :

http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/bbj8k9pe/

Comment: Not sure what the problem is as your jsfiddle doesn't look like the screenshot, build logic to not render the control element when there's no further children.

Comment: @Scuzzy, How can I decided that there is no more children after this parent and disappear it.

Comment: What is different between your code and that sample code? that sample code appears to do the job you want without the plus or minus UI controls?

Comment: Nothing, Yes I want plus or minus UI controls, But  when parent have no more  child then it will disappear. In above 250,500,1000 module have plus sign that I dont want any plus or minus sign, In short if it  is leaf (When the row has no children) then i dont want any sign.